# Solving a trigonometric equation

Tags: calculus

Let $n=3m$ and $k=3t$ be positive integers. Does the following equation have any solutions for $0 \leq j \leq n-1$

$$\cos \left ( \frac{2\pi j (k+1)}{n}\right )+\cos\left (\frac{2\pi j (k-1)}{n} \right ) =\frac{1}{2}.$$

Is there any idea to make it more simply?

Comment: Are $m$ and $t$ also integers?

Comment: Is to the second fraction no function applied?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Yes, right.

Comment: I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the addition theorems you get
$$\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)=2\cos(x)\cos(y).$$

So in our case we are looking for a solution of
$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi j t}{m}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2\pi j}{3m}\right)=\frac{1}{4}.$$